# Magento Go Translation fails with error message Translation is absent in source locale translation file

Tags: localisation, magento-go

I am trying to translate a Magento Go interface into Norwegian and I am using the files from the support website.  When I try to upload the translation, it ignores a few entries with an error message "Translation is absent in source locale translation file", any clues on how this can be overcome, since it is Magento Go, I am a little unfamiliar with how this can be resolved.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks, happy to provide any clarifications.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Magento Go is Closed as of February 1st 2015

Answer (score 1):

Can you point me to the support website translation files? This happens when your file has rows that do not correspond to translation identifiers in the current version of Go. Possibly you are using files from a different version. You should still be able to see the other rows translated. The right procedure is to skip this error by clicking Continue, downloading the translations files from Go again and reviewing if anything is missing - then upload again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, here is the url http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations/ this was not meant for Magento Go, the version used is 1.1.2.2 I am not sure how to find out the version this URL is meant for